# SQL Server Developer edition and SharePoint

Tags: 2013, sql, sql-server-2012

Can you use SQL Server Developer Edition with SharePoint 2013?

Would each service account need a license?

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Check the list of all **[Supported and Unsupported SQL Server for SharePoint 2016 and 2013](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sql-server-2016-sp1-support-sharepoint-2016/#sql-server-version-for-sharepoint-2013)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can install SharePoint owith SQL Server Developer edition. [Check this](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/4/A/64A1EC8F-F575-41E1-9D34-821FA9F98F8E/SQL_Server_2012_Licensing_Reference_Guide.pdf)

**Licensing SQL Server for Non-production Use**

The SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition is a full-function version of the SQL Server software—with all the features and capabilities of the Enterprise edition—licensed under the Developer Tools model, which is a **“per user”** model. One license is required for each person that accesses or uses the software.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1760a965-8012-499b-94e3-b3b724f9a7b3/installing-sharepoint-2013-with-sql-server-2012-developer-edition?forum=sharepointadmin

I never used this as we Have MSDN subscription so we use that license.

Comment: Great, so then this would mean each SharePoint Service account needs a license?

Comment: its depend, some cover under the device call and some user call...http://blogs.technet.com/b/uspartner_ts2team/archive/2013/11/05/administrative-amp-service-account-cals.aspx also check this pdf http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/8/9/68964284-864d-4a6d-aed9-f2c1f8f23e14/Assessing_SharePoint_Server_Licensing.pdf